# Proof by contradiction for sequences

Tags: functional-analysis

There is no sequence $(c_n)_n ∈ l^1$, such that a sequence $(x_n)_n$ is in $l^1$ if and only if there is a $K>0$ with $|x_n| ≤ K|c_n|$

For this what I understand is I need to use proof by contradiction by using the inverse mapping theorem to show that $l^1$ is isomorphic to $l^∞$. The problem is that I don't know how to visualize this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1** Assume $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|c_n|<\infty.$ Therefore $c_n\to 0.$ Hence there exists an increasing sequence of positive integers $n_k$ such that $|c_{n_k}|\le 4^{-k}.$ The sequence $$x_n=\begin{cases} 2^{-k} & n=n_k\\ 0 & n\neq n_k\end{cases}$$belongs to $\ell^1$ but $${x_{n_k}\over |c_{n_k}|}\ge {2^{-k}\over 4^{-k}}=2^k\to \infty$$

**Solution 2** This solution is an overkill. Let $$A=\{ x\in \ell^1\,:\, |x_n|\le |c_n|\}$$ Then $A$ is nowhere dense in $\ell^1.$ Indeed if $x\in A$ then for any fixed $\delta >0$ we have $x+\delta e_n\notin A$ for large $n,$ as $c_n\to 0.$ Assume $$\ell^1=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (kA)$$ Then $X$ is of first category, which in view of the Baire category theorem leads to a contradiction.